# Conditional constraint in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm having a problem creating a conditional constraint included within table creation in Microsoft SQL Server. I just can't seem to figure it out.

I've tried `case` statements, `if then` statements, nothing seems to work.

Is this even possible because I keep getting a syntax error?

```
CREATE TABLE SECTION
(
    c# int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Course(c#),
    se# int,
    emp# int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Professor(EMP#),
    class_time time,
    controlNumber int DEFAULT 20,
    CONSTRAINT pk_SectionID PRIMARY KEY (c#, se#),
    CONSTRAINT chk_controlNumber CHECK (controlNumber >= 40 AND controlNumber <=60),

    CONSTRAINT chk_c# CHECK (when c# between 3000 and 5000 then controlNumber <=40)
);
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: just remove `when ` and replace `between` by `AND` operator

Comment: the error I was getting was: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'when'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine your two checks since otherwise they're contradictory, and then just combine them with simple boolean logic:

```
CREATE TABLE SECTION(
    c# int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Course(c#),
    se# int,
    emp# int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Professor(EMP#),
    class_time time,
    controlNumber int DEFAULT 20,
    CONSTRAINT pk_SectionID PRIMARY KEY (c#, se#),
    CONSTRAINT chk_controlNumber CHECK (
      controlNumber between 40 AND 60 and (c# < 3000 or c# > 5000) or
      (c# between 3000 and 5000 and controlNumber <= 40))
);
```

Comment: This solution is very concise and is working perfectly. Thank you.